# Adorner does not apply DataTemplates from Resources within ContentPresenter

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate, adorner, contentpresenter

I have an Adorner that is used to give visual feedback while drag'n drop. The Adorner internally uses a ContentPresenter to display (non-visual) content. When I use a Visual as content the (visual) object correctly gets rendered, but when I use a non-visual object the Adorner and its ContentPresenter only calls ToString() and does not apply any DataTemplates that are given.

**Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong that the DataTemplates are not used to render the non-visual objects on Adorner layer?**

Here is a simplified sample code:

Adorner:

```
internal class ContentAdorner : System.Windows.Documents.Adorner
{
    private readonly ContentPresenter contentPresenter = new ContentPresenter();

    public ContentAdorner(UIElement adornedElement)
        : base(adornedElement)
    {
    }

    public object Content
    {
        get
        {
            return this.contentPresenter.Content;
        }

        set
        {
            this.contentPresenter.Content = value;
        }
    }

    protected override int VisualChildrenCount
    {
        get
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index)
    {
        return this.contentPresenter;
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        Rect rect = new Rect(finalSize);

        this.contentPresenter.Arrange(rect);

        return finalSize;
    }

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
    {
        this.contentPresenter.Measure(constraint);

        return this.contentPresenter.DesiredSize;
    }

    protected override System.Collections.IEnumerator LogicalChildren
    {
        get
        {
            ArrayList list = new ArrayList()
            {
                this.contentPresenter,
            };

            return list.GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
}
```

Non-visual class that is used as Content within Adorner:

```
    internal class Model {}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="Adorner.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Adorner"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" AllowDrop="True">
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Model}">
        <Rectangle Fill="Yellow" Width="50" Height="50"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid Name="myGrid">
    <ContentControl MouseMove="ContentControl_MouseMove"
                    DragOver="ContentControl_DragOver">
        <ContentControl.Content>
            <local:Model/> 
        </ContentControl.Content>
    </ContentControl>
</Grid>
```

Code behind MainWindow.xaml:

```
    private void ContentControl_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            Model model = ((ContentControl)sender).Content as Model;

            DataObject dataObject = new DataObject("Model", model);

            DragDrop.DoDragDrop(sender as DependencyObject, dataObject, DragDropEffects.Move);
        }
    }

    private void ContentControl_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        Model model = (Model)e.Data.GetData("Model");

        ContentAdorner adorner = new ContentAdorner(this.myGrid)
        {
            Content = model,
        };

        AdornerLayer layer = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(this.myGrid);

        layer.Add(adorner);
    }
```

It seems that this question handles the same problem: [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13543106/resolving-datatemplate-for-contentpresenter-inside-custom-frameworkelement)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

The Adorner layer does not know the resources of the MainWindow. You can either manually add the specific DataTemplates to the Resources of the Adorner or use the Themes/Generic.xaml together with the ThemeInfo attribute in AssemblyInfo.cs file to specify the DataTemplates.